# How can I retrieve record using date as parameter in cloud code?

Tags: parse-platform

I have an event class, from which I have to fetch all the events occurring at particular date. For that I have created a cloud function with date as parameter , but I am getting result as empty set.

Here is my cloud code:

Parse.Cloud.define("events", function(request, response) {

```
var event = Parse.Object.extend("event");
var query = new Parse.Query(event);
query.equalTo("From", request.params.From);
query.find({
success: function(results) 
{
    response.success(results);
},
error: function(error) 
{
    response.success("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
}
});
```

});

I tried calling this function using curl but its shows empty result set, and also tried using

var tdate = new Date(); Parse.Cloud.run('events',{ From: tdate}, { success: function(response) { alert(response); }, error: function(error) { } });

How can I get record of particular date using cloud code?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue... see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790239/filter-on-own-date-fields-no-working-and-or-wrong-date-format-used) which I'd answered myself, validated with proper testing.

you need to change your filter line in a way that provides a correct **date** data type, as below:

```
query.equalTo("From", new Date(request.params.From));
```