# Filter on own date fields no working and/or wrong date format used

Tags: parse-platform

When doing a filter on my own date fields I don't get expected records, while I do get the records when filtering by parse default date fields.

Below piece of code should return the last two records from the JSON provided at the end.

Notice that **createdAt** is the default parse date field, while **startDate** is my own date field.

So in the filter you can change for the working and failing part of the code.

I think it has something to do with the format of the data provided to the query filter function.  I'd done many tests though, and I cannot find the proper format that I should work with

Working:

```
query.greaterThan("createdAt", date2.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"));
```

Failing:

```
query.greaterThan("startDate", date2.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"));
```

Code used:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("dateChecks", function(request, response){
    var message;
    var date2 = momento('2014-12-20T00:00:00+00:00');
    console.log("date2: " + date2.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"));
    var query = new Parse.Query("myClass");
    query.greaterThan("createdAt", date2.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"));
    query.find({
        success: function(resultList) {
            for (var i = 0; i < resultList.length; ++i) {
                message = "\ncomments: " + resultList[i].get("comments") + " \tstartDate: " + resultList[i].get("startDate") + " \tcreatedAt: " + resultList[i].get("createdAt");
                console.log(message);
            }
            response.success(resultList);
            },
        error: function() {
                //response.error("Failured.  Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                response.error("Things have gone wrong!!!");
        }
    });
});
```

JSON used:

```
    { "results": [
{
    "comments": "1",
    "createdAt": "2014-12-18T20:56:40.176Z",
    "startDate": {
        "__type": "Date",
        "iso": "2015-01-05T10:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "objectId": "juRygHvpw5",
    "updatedAt": "2015-01-05T21:11:31.463Z"
},
{
    "comments": "7",
    "createdAt": "2014-12-20T00:35:03.617Z",
    "startDate": {
        "__type": "Date",
        "iso": "2015-01-15T09:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "objectId": "vtlGCgZVZD",
    "updatedAt": "2015-01-05T20:53:09.327Z"
},
{
    "comments": "6",
    "createdAt": "2014-12-20T00:32:48.884Z",
    "startDate": {
        "__type": "Date",
        "iso": "2015-01-15T14:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "objectId": "JARVIQKFxq",
    "updatedAt": "2015-01-05T20:53:07.671Z"
}
] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it results, at least from my testing, that you cannot pass any momentjs instance when filtering on date fields... it will fail as described in my question.

after using a Date datatype things worked properly.

basically changes are:

```
var filterDate = new Date(date2.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"))
var query = new Parse.Query("myClass");
query.greaterThan("startDate", filterDate);
```

full code that worked for me is:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("dateChecks", function(request, response){
    var message;

    var date2 = momento('2015-01-15T00:00:00+00:00');
    console.log("date2: " + date2.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"));
    var filterDate = new Date(date2.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"))
    console.log("filterDate: " + filterDate);

    var query = new Parse.Query("myClass");
    query.greaterThan("startDate", filterDate);
    query.find({
        success: function(resultList) {
            for (var i = 0; i < resultList.length; ++i) {
                message = "\ncomments: " + resultList[i].get("comments") + " \tstartDate: " + resultList[i].get("inicioCita") + " \tcreatedAt: " + resultList[i].get("createdAt");
                console.log(message);
            }
            response.success(resultList);
        },
        error: function() {
            //response.error("Failured.  Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            response.error("Things have gone wrong!!!");
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps anyone out there!!!